# How can I restrict a guest account from accessing the Group Policy Editor?

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, gpedit

I am the admin of a Windows XP machine and I would like to make so that the guest account cannot access the Group Policy Editor. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have added the "guest" into another group, they shouldn't be able to access it.

Default permissions are as follows for "gpedit.msc":

```
Administrators   = Full Control
Power Users      = Read & Execute
SYSTEM           = Full Control
Users            = Read & Execute
```

Comment: On the contrary, the guest account is a member of Users, so they can indeed access the `.msc` file, although that doesn't mean they can access group policy.